# Ruby - Net::FTP - Binary and Text file

Tags: ruby, text, ftp, binary, byte

I'm new to Ruby, and i'm making a script to download FTP Data from the server.
I'm not sure I quite fully understand getbinaryfile and gettextfile. I know there is the difference of byte handling over the net, but can't I just use getbinaryfile for both Binary and Text files ? If that wouldn't be a recommended practice, what should I use for checking whether the file is Binary or Text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getbinaryfile` or `gettextfile` [map directly](http://www.rhinosoft.com/newsletter/NewsL2008-03-18.asp) onto the [FTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) which has a binary/image mode and ascii/text mode.

The safe bet is to always default to binary mode. You could use `gettextfile` if you know for sure that the file is text, that is, screened against a whitelist of text files such as *.php, *.txt etc.

If you use `gettextfile` for a binary you might get a corrupted file, because `getbinaryfile` should have been used.